@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS) with @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY ) warn
When I put the TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance type strategy in the parent class, the tables are generated as expected, however, the same warning appears below, referring to all relationships (@ManyToOne, @OneToMany) and child classes:
2024-09-07T11:28:50.495-03:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m11572[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[armamentsection] [  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table equipament_weapon add constraint FKl2954vmi9jp9kciej0w9ls0x1 foreign key (model_id) references equipament_model (id)" via JDBC [Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'FKl2954vmi9jp9kciej0w9ls0x1']

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table equipament_weapon add constraint FKl2954vmi9jp9kciej0w9ls0x1 foreign key (model_id) references equipament_model (id)" via JDBC [Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'FKl2954vmi9jp9kciej0w9ls0x1']
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:575) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:515) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:447) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:268) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1506) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:682) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1705) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1454) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1375) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1212) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1375) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1212) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:174) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:169) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:154) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:87) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:266) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:240) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:52) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4414) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:772) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:203) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:415) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:874) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:437) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:128) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:107) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:516) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:222) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:188) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:619) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at com.fariamiguel.ArmamentSectionApplication.main(ArmamentSectionApplication.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'FKl2954vmi9jp9kciej0w9ls0x1'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:770) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:653) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    ... 127 common frames omitted

Parent Class
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Inheritance;
import jakarta.persistence.InheritanceType;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.PrePersist;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Equipament implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Column( name = "numeration" )
    private String numeration;

    @JsonFormat( pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" )
    @Column( name = "registration_date" )
    private Date registrationDate;
    
    // -----

     @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
     @JoinColumn( name="model_id" ) 
     private EquipamentModel model;
      
     @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
     @JoinColumn( name="current_condition_id" ) 
     private EquipamentCurrentCondition currentCondition;
     
     @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
     @JoinColumn( name="acquisition_origin_id" ) 
     private EquipamentAcquisitionOrigin acquisitionOrigin;
      
      @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
      @JoinColumn( name="acquisition_status_id" ) private
      EquipamentAcquisitionStatus acquisitionStatus;
      
     @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
     @JoinColumn( name="current_situation_id" ) 
     private EquipamentCurrentSituation currentSituation;
    
     @OneToMany( mappedBy = "equipament" ) 
     private List<TransferredEquipament> transferredEquipaments;
     
     @OneToMany( mappedBy = "equipament" ) 
     private List<VigilancedEquipament> vigilancedEquipaments;
    
    // -----
    
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        Date now = new Date();
        setRegistrationDate( now );
    }
    
}

Classe Filha
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode( callSuper = false )
@Table( name = "equipament_weapon" )

public class EquipamentWeapon extends Equipament {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Column( name = "charger_quantity" )
    private Integer chargerQuantity;
    
    @Column( name = "shotting_capacity" )
    private Integer shottingCapacity;
    
    //-----
    
    public EquipamentWeapon(Long id, String numeration, Date registrationDate, EquipamentModel model,
            EquipamentCurrentCondition currentCondition, EquipamentAcquisitionOrigin acquisitionOrigin,
            EquipamentAcquisitionStatus acquisitionStatus, EquipamentCurrentSituation currentSituation,
            List<TransferredEquipament> transferredEquipaments, List<VigilancedEquipament> vigilancedEquipaments,
            Integer chargerQuantity, Integer shottingCapacity) {
        
        super(id, numeration, registrationDate, model, currentCondition, acquisitionOrigin, acquisitionStatus, currentSituation,
                    transferredEquipaments, vigilancedEquipaments);
        this.chargerQuantity = chargerQuantity;
        this.shottingCapacity = shottingCapacity;
        
    }

}

Relacionamento @ManyToOne
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.PrePersist;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table( name = "equipament_model" )
public class EquipamentModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column( name = "model" )
    private String model;

    @JsonFormat( pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" )
    @Column( name = "registrationDate" )
    private Date registrationDate;
    
    // -----

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn( name="brand_id" )
    private EquipamentBrand brand;
    
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "model" ) 
    private List<Equipament> equipaments;
    
    // -----
    
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        Date now = new Date();
        setRegistrationDate( now );
    }
    
}

Some help please.
Thanks!
I believe I have searched and tried everything I knew and found on the internet, but it doesn't change. I need to resolve this situation, or change to the JOINED inheritance type.

You can try this sample code it might help you:

Parent Class

package vn.com.minh.svi.core.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import vn.com.minh.svi.core.singleton.RequestContext;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@MappedSuperclass
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class BaseStringIdEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "uuid"
)
@Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, length = 32, unique = true)
@Size(max = 32)
protected String id;

@Column(name = "create_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
protected LocalDateTime createAt;
@Column(name = "update_time", nullable = false)
protected LocalDateTime updateTime;

@Column(name = "create_by", length = 32, updatable = false, nullable = false)
protected String createBy;
@Column(name = "update_by", length = 32, nullable = false)
protected String updateBy;

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    final LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    this.createAt = now;
    this.updateTime = now;
    this.createBy = RequestContext.getContext().getUserId();
    this.updateBy = RequestContext.getContext().getUserId();
}
@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdate() {
    this.updateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    this.updateBy = RequestContext.getContext().getUserId();
}

}

Child Class

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@Table(name = "template_plot_registration")
public class TemplatePlotRegistrationEntity extends BaseStringIdEntity {

@Column(name = "template_plot_id", length = 32, updatable = false)
private String templatePlotId;

@Column(name = "evaluation_criteria_id", length = 32, updatable = false)
private String evaluationCriteriaId;

@Column(name = "template_id", length = 32, updatable = false)
private String templateId;

@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "template_plot_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private TemplatePlotEntity templatePlot;

@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "evaluation_criteria_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private EvaluationCriteriaEntity evaluationCriteria;

}
Hope that helps you.

Thanks, but it doesn't work with MappedSuperClass because I need to use Entity due to the associations. I had already tried before. There are more child classes, and they all have the same associations. If I put the associations directly in the child classes there will be a lot of code repetition.
